# Multinomial logistic regression power analysis

Tags: regression, statistical-power, multinomial-distribution

I am looking to conduct a power analysis for a multinomial logistic regression. Categorical outcome variable (3-response measures) and two continuous predictor variables (and an interaction of them both). I also have 7 covariates (gender, age, ethnicity, education, employment status, political orientation, household income). Can anyone advise me as to how I should run a power analysis? I have 151 participants (I'd imagine the study will be quite underpowered given the number of variables).

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You should probably run a simulation.

Comment: Thank you! How would I do this?

Comment: It's not easy to describe, because it's a long process. Generate the data that matches your alternative hypothesis (including all variances and covariances (perhaps using mvrnorm from the MASS package in R), then analyse, and see if you get significant results. Then repeat (something like) 10,000 times.